# Image downloaded from Parse will not show up as UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

The code in question is

```
    if let productImageFile = productData!["productImage"] as? PFFile {
                    productImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let imageData = imageData {
                                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                    self.productImageView.image = image
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I am getting no errors whatsoever, but the image just doesn't want to load from Parse. Everything else loads and displays just fine, but the image never loads no matter how long I wait. If I change the UIImageView to PFImageView, and change the UIImageView's class to PFImageView in Interface Builder, it gives me 3 linker errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_kPFErrorInvalidImageData", referenced from: ___32-[PFImageView loadInBackground:]_block_invoke30 in ParseUI(PFImageView.o) 
"_kPFErrorUnsavedFile", referenced from: -[PFImageView loadInBackground:] in ParseUI(PFImageView.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any help is appreciated. Full ViewController code below.

```
    import UIKit
    import Parse
    import Bolts
    import ParseUI

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var dayOfTheWeekLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var productPriceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var buyButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Create new PFQuery to retrieve info from Parse
    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "MyProduct")

    //function to get the data
    func getProductData (){
        //call function to get the data from parse by specifyng an objectId
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("XXXXXXXXXX") {
            (productData:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && productData != nil {
                //Extract values from the productData PFObject and store them in constants
                let dayOfTheWeek = productData!.objectForKey("day") as! String
                let productTitle = productData!.objectForKey("productTitle") as! String
                //-----start image loading
                if let productImageFile = productData!["productImage"] as? PFFile {
                    productImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let imageData = imageData {
                                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                    self.productImageView.image = image
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //-----end image loading
                let productPrice = productData!.objectForKey("productPrice") as! String
                let productDescription = productData!.objectForKey("productDescription") as! String

                //take the saved constants and assign their values to the labels and UIImage on screen
                self.productTitleLabel.text = productTitle
                self.dayOfTheWeekLabel.text = dayOfTheWeek
                //self.productImageView.image! = productImageFile
                self.productPriceLabel.text = productPrice
                self.productDescriptionLabel.text = productDescription

            } else if error != nil {
                println("Could not load data from Parse")
            }



        }

    }


    //Print out a message if we're able to get to this part of the program.
    println("Reached getProductData function. Now asking for data.")
            getProductData()

}
```

Comment: What errors do you get when using `PFImageView`? Using `PFImageView` would make your code shorter and simpler.

Comment: I get 3 Apple Mach-O Linker errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_kPFErrorInvalidImageData", referenced from:
      ___32-[PFImageView loadInBackground:]_block_invoke30 in ParseUI(PFImageView.o)
  "_kPFErrorUnsavedFile", referenced from:
      -[PFImageView loadInBackground:] in ParseUI(PFImageView.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: So I just tried changing the image loading block of code to the code below and I'm still getting the same error.

         var productImageFile = UIImage(named: "productImage")
                    if let imageFile = productData?["productImage"] as? PFFile {
                        self.productImageView.file = imageFile
                        self.productImageView.loadInBackground()
                    }

Comment: Undefined symbols says you are missing some piece of code or libraries. Did you include the ParseUI libraries to your project as well?

Comment: Yes I did. I double-checked and made sure it's in the linked libraries as well :(